# Замена картинок | preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не получается написать регулярное выражение, которое заменяло бы все пути с картинками. Код:

```
preg_replace(
    "/[http|\/](.+?)" . basename($content_image) . "/i",
    $img_origin,
    $result["content"]
);
```

В коде картинки могут начинаться как с http так и просто со слеша. А так же мне известно название картинки. Но в итоге ничего не заменяется.

Пример строки:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://site.com/">sit</a> amet. <a href="/uploads/test.jpg"><img src="/uploads/test.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: `"/(?:http|\/).+?" . preg_quote(basename($content_image), "/") . "/i"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew не работает

Comment: Приведите пример строки и желаемый результат + все необходимые известные переменные.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew привел

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew не работает так. У Вас стирается весь тест после того как он нашел первую ссылку.`$img_origin` - это путь к картинке который будет подставлен вместо найденного. `$content_image` - старое название картинки вместе, которое как раз и требуется заменить.

Comment: Т.е. надо так - https://3v4l.org/AQGKR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если и этот пример у вас окажется *не рабочим*, значит вы явно не правильно сформулировали ваш вопрос:

```
$str = <<<STR
    Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://site.com/">sit</a> amet. <a href="/uploads/test.jpg"><img src="/uploads/test.jpg" alt=""></a>
STR;

$pcre = '~(?:href|src)="\K[^"]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif)~s';
$repl = 'Значение для замены';

$str = preg_replace($pcre, $repl, $str);

echo $str;
```

Результат:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://site.com/">sit</a> amet. <a href="Значение для замены"><img src="Значение для замены" alt=""></a>
```

---

При необходимости можно дописать остальные расширения графических файлов в конструкцию `(?:jpg|png|gif)`

Comment: Ура! Наконец-то. Ваш код работает правильно, только я заменил немного концовку `"~(?:href|src)=\"\K[^\"]+" . preg_quote(basename($content_image), "/") . "~s"`, так как я не все картинки заменяю однотипно, а каждый индивидуально. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Использую для проверки картинки-ссылки, в одной проверке, вот такую регулярку

$url = preg_match('/([^\s]+(?=.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)).\2)/', $url);

Пример работы регулярки на JQ

```js
$('.url').each(function(){
  let url = $(this).text(),
      urlCheck = url.match(/([^\s]+(?=\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png))\.\2)/g);
  
  $(this).append('<b> - это'+(urlCheck == null ? ' НЕ ' : ' ')+'картинка</b>').find('b').css('color', urlCheck == null ? 'red' : 'green');
});
```

```css
.url {display: block;}
.url b {font-weight: normal;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="url">http://site.com/image.jpg</span>
<span class="url">http://site.com/image.html</span>
<span class="url">https://site.com/image.jpg</span>
<span class="url">https://site.com/image.html</span>
<span class="url">http://www.site.com/image.jpg</span>
<span class="url">http://www.site.com/image.html</span>
<span class="url">https://www.site.com/image.jpg</span>
<span class="url">https://www.site.com/image.html</span>
<span class="url">www.site.com/image.jpg</span>
<span class="url">www.site.com/image.html</span>
<span class="url">site.com/image.jpg</span>
<span class="url">site.com/image.html</span>
<span class="url">/image.jpg</span>
<span class="url">/image.html</span>
```

Источник [регулярки](https://vk.com/doc123534285_437343207)

Comment: У меня известно каждое название картинки, типа name.jpg, я перебираю все картинки и нахожу каждую и заменяю на свой путь. Ваш вариант к сожалению не работает, в крайнем случае мне он не подходит.